# How to replace the linux nano editor when visual studio code is available?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, editor, nano

I would like replace the nano command when I am using a Terminal Session with remote ssh in  Visual Studio Code.

Why I need it?
Using different linux server not always I have the code editor available and I am live little frustating mitstakes:
I often write nano when code is available and sometimes I write code in putty.

I would like a special "nano" command / function:
if code is available then execute code
else execute nano
end if

Of course other way are accepted.

thanks

UPDATE: I changed a bit the function and this one works fine.

```
function nano() {
if [[ $(type -t code) = "file" ]]; then
    code "$@"
else
    command nano "$@"
fi
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the way to do that you want is create a "alias" in the bashrc file of the system.

```
alias nano='command to open vscode'
```

To open VSCode insteand of Nano if it is installed, this alias has to be created into a if statement.

```
if [ <check if installed> ]
then
 <alias to open vscode>
fi
```

If vscode is not installed default nano will open. But, if you use different Linux Systems you need to do this configuration at each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming VSCode is installed at /usr/bin/code, try this :

```
nano(){
    local cmd=/usr/bin/code
    if test -x "$cmd"; then
        "$cmd" "$@"
    else
        command nano "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: seems not working.
I tried the following in the same server ubuntu 20.04
Terminal session using VS Code with SSH
    type -t code return file
Putty session
    type -t code return a empty value
How I can test the output of type command?

Comment: I changed you function using type and it works like a charm!
Thanks of idea...I will reply to mine to post a better formatted code.

`# - "Command" nano will open Visual Studio Code is available otherwise the real nano
function nano() {
    local cmd=/usr/bin/code
    if [[ $(type -t code) = "file" ]]; then
        code "$@"
    else
        command nano "$@"
    fi
}
`